# Associate the possessive adjective to a neutral noun

Tags: noun, adjective, possessive

You want to associate the possessive adjective to the possessor (noun). If you have a masculine noun, you use

> sein/seine/sein

If the possessor is feminine, you use

> ihr/ihre/ihr

What about a neuter possessor? I understand that if this neuter possessor is a masculine or feminine person, you use the corresponding adjective, but what about all of those nouns which do not refer to people, like for example "das Brot"?

Comment: There are even people with neuter gender: *"das Mädchen"* which will confuse even us native Germans when we have to use the appropriate possessive pronoun. ;)

Comment: I know, and _"das Kind"_ can be both a male and a female...!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The possessor’s grammatical gender is neutral, the corresponding possessive pronoun is sein/seine/sein (which is identical to the pronoun for a possessor of male grammatical gender) – no matter what the possessor’s biological gender. However, sometimes the possessive pronoun corresponding to the possessor’s biological gender is used in a [constructio ad sensum](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructio_ad_sensum), especially if the biological gender is known, which is the case for the word *Mädchen,* for example.

Some examples:

> *Das Mädchen* spielte mit *seinem* Auto. – The girl played with her car. (correct)
>    *Das Mädchen* spielte mit *ihrem* Auto. (constructio ad sensum)
>    Ich nahm *das Brot* und schnitt durch *seine* Kruste – I took the bread and cut through its crust.

Addendum:
Fascinatingly, I have never seen a constructio ad sensum, if *Person,* which is of female grammatical gender, is used to refer to a clearly male person.

> Die Polizei sucht eine unbekannte männliche *Person,* die *ihre* Haare grün gefärbt hatte. – The police is looking for an unknown male person, who dyed his hair green.

Comment: Constructio ad sensum is not applicable here as grammatical genus and biological sex or gender are totally independant.

Comment: So, according to Wrzlprmft, it would be (it is feasible) "das Mädchen und ihr Pferd", according to Toscho it would be "das Mädchen und sein Pferd" instead. I'm confused. Do you have some reference for this?

Comment: @Toscho: Though the German language currently suffers from people massively overinterpreting the connection between grammatical and biological gender, it is not true that there is no connection at all. Either way, this is the textbook example for the constructio ad sensum in German. Just search the Internet for *"constructio ad sensum" Mädchen* and you will get several sources for this.

Comment: @Martina: Though I have no proof at hand, I am pretty certain, that in the special case of *Mädchen,* referring to this word with a female pronoun (das Mädchen und ihr Pferd) is accepted to the extent, that most copy editors will accept it. As mentioned above, this is *the* textbook example for the constructio ad sensum in German. Still, there is nothing wrong about the grammatically correct option (das Mädchen und sein Pferd), and I would almost always prefer it.

Comment: I think it's worth to mention that this follows the same pattern for the missing neuter indefinite article. "Das Mädchen" is "Ein Mädchen" and "Das Stück Brot" ist "Ein Stück Brot".

Comment: @martina From a grammatical point of view it's correct to go with the masculine gender. In colloquial speech, however, it's **very common** to neglect this rule if talking about female people, namely "Mädchen" or "Kind". I'd even highly recommend to do so as it is very awkward to refer to a girl as "him".

Comment: @Em1: I would not say that any neuter forms are missing. They just happen to be identical with the masculine forms. So, I would not perceive that a girl is referred to as *him,* but as *it* (which is about the same concerning the awkwardness, hence the neglection of grammar and constructio ad sensum).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I don't know about the textbooks, but constructio ad sensum is a grammatically incorrect form, that is correct in its sense. If the possive pronoun of "Pferd" is referencing the word "das Mädchen", then "sein" is correct and "ihr" is incorrect, but both grammatically and by its sense. If the pronoun is referencing the person described as "Mädchen", then "sein" is incorrect and "ihr" is correct (from a biological POV neglecting sociological gender), but only by sense as you have left the rules of grammar by referencing to something nonlingual.

Comment: Concerning the constructio ad sensum for male persons: Your example mixes male/female and possesive pronoun/relativ pronoun. Make a strictly possesive example in order to compare with "Mädchen":

Eine männliche Person hatte einen Unfall. Sein Auto war kaputt. -- Eine männliche Person hatte einen Unfall. Ihr Auto war kaputt.

Answer (score 1):

Neuter nouns have the same possesive pronouns as masculin nouns. It has *nothing* to do with biological sexes or genders.